# Select everyone with the same ips

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table of users `users`:

```
+----+---------+------------+  
| id |  login  |      ip    |
+----+---------+------------+  
|  1 |  user1  |  127.0.0.1 |  
|  2 |  user2  |  127.0.0.1 |  
+----+---------+------------+
```

ETC...

It is necessary to select all users with 1 `ip`.

```
SELECT u1.id, u1.login, u1.ip FROM users AS u1 LEFT JOIN users as u2 ON u1.ip = u2.ip;
```

I tried to do it, it doesn't work, not what I need to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ip) cnt
              FROM source_table )
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE cnt > 1
```

For MySQL 5.x use

```
SELECT *
FROM source_table t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM source_table t2
               WHERE t1.ip = t2.ip 
                 AND t1.id != t2.id )
```

Comment: Not working. `PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte AS ( SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ip) cnt FROM users ) SELECT * FRO' at line 1`

Comment: @FixiDens If you use **not** the most recent server version you must specify this in the question explicitly. PS. Updated.